# Entirely in QML, Web Service call etc

Tags: blackberry-10

So far I built most of my UI and logic in QML with JavaScript without touching the C++. But now I need to make a RESTFul API call, based upon the examples I saw so far I must write the call code in C++ then "some how" (Am still figuring out that part) get it in the QML/JavaScript world....

Can't i make the API call etc completely etc in QML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in REST but in theory if you could write the call in JavaScript running in a browser, you should be able to make the the same call using very similar JavaScript in QML/JS.

Having said that one of the things you want to do to maintain the responsiveness of your application is not run any time consuming routines on the event thread. Ensuring this is the case is quite easy in C++, I'm nos sure you could do that as easily in JS.

Finally it is relatively easy to get the results back to JavaScript world is quite easy. Qt and Cascades has a rich data modeling component set. QVariantList and QVariantMap types map into JS arrays.